# Exec format error when locating a variable at a given absolute memory address (Cygwin)

Tags: c, variables, gcc, window, cygwin

The following code places a variable at a given absolute address in memory using a Linker file. When I run the code under Cygwin, it fails. But running it under Linux works fine. How can I emulate it for Windows using Cygwin?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int count __attribute__((section(".countSection"))) = 0;

int main(void) {
    printf("adr %p\n", &count);
    return 0;
}
```

link.ld

```
SECTIONS
{
  .mySegment 0x44444444 : {KEEP(*(.countSection))}
}
```

compile

```
gcc -fno-pie -no-pie -o main.exe link.ld main.c
```

run

```
./main.exe
cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Comment: You must be eliding the `link.ld` on your linux command line. Otherwise, I get an error: `/usr/bin/ld: warning: link.ld contains output sections; did you forget -T?` Without `link.ld` it works fine [on linux]. When I use `-Tlink.ld`, I get `not enough room for program headers, try linking with -N`